# Is it possible to template the asm opcode in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, assembly, gcc, inline-assembly

I want something like this:

```cpp
template <const char *op, int lane_select>
static int cmpGT64Sx2(V64x2 x, V64x2 y)
{
   int result;
   __asm__("movups %1,%%xmm6\n"
           "\tmovups %2,%%xmm7\n"
           // order swapped for AT&T style which has destination second.
           "\t " op " %%xmm7,%%xmm6\n"
           "\tpextrb %3, %%xmm6, %0"
           : "=r" (result) : "m" (x), "m" (y), "i" (lane_select*8) : "xmm6");
   return result;
}
```

Clearly it has to be a template because it must be known at compile time.  The lane_select works fine already and it is a template but it's an operand.  I want the `op` that is in the asm to be different, like either `pcmpgtd` or `pcmpgtq`, etc.  If it helps: I always want some form of x86's `pcmpgt`, with just the final letter changing.

Edit:

This is a test case for valgrind where it's very important that the exact instruction is run so that we can examine if the definedness of the output.

Comment: You realize this is going to be worse than just using intrinsics, right?  Like `_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i)&x)` and y, then `_mm_cmpgt_epi32` or `64` (which you could select between with an `if()` on a compile-time constant).  Then `_mm_movemask_ps` or `_epi8` to get a bitmap of the SIMD compare result.  Or if you want just the nth member, do it in pure C with `memcpy` or other alias-safe loads into `int32_t` or `int64_t` members from an offset into `x` and `y`.

Comment: Also, you're missing a clobber on `xmm7`.  Probably better to just ask the compiler for the inputs to be in two `"x"` inputs, instead of taking memory source inputs that force the compiler to have the objects in memory.

Comment: `pcmpgt%z1` would *almost* work if you had a dummy output operand whose type was int32_t or int64_t.  `%z[op]` is the AT&T size suffix, b/w/l/q, so it's `l` for dword, not d.  Perhaps something with GAS `.macro` or `.if` (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/If.html#If) using an `"i"` input for the template param (as an integer char value or simple boolean 0 or 1, not a pointer of course).

Comment: @PeterCordes Why is it worse than intrinsics?  I don't know anything about intrinsics.  I have edited the question to explain that the goal is valgrind testing.

Comment: Use intrinsics. Don't use inline assembly unless you have no other option. This sort of code isn't really maintainable and unless you know *exactly* what you're doing assembly-wise you're going to mess something up. It's much harder to foul up intrinsics, and the compiler can warn if you do. Inside `__asm__` you're on your own.

Comment: It's worse because you're forcing the operands to exist in memory for `movups` instead of already in a register (to fix that, use `"+x"` and `"x"` inputs), and you're forcing use of XMM6 and 7 for this instead of the compiler's choice.  (e.g. those two are call-preserved on Windows x64).  Also, SSE4.1 `pextrb` is a pretty clunky way to get a compare result out vs. `pmovmskb`.  You hadn't said before that you needed this exact instruction to run; for other use cases it would be an *advantage* that `_mm_cmpgt_epi64` could maybe optimize into something else, or a constant with constant inputs.

Comment: It's also worse because you as tadman said, it's very easy to create bugs.  Your code already has one: like I said, missing "xmm7" clobber.  (Better, just use two `"=x"` dummy outputs to let the compiler pick registers, or make them input and in/out so you can leave the `movups` out of the template.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the advice.  I have tried intrinsics and I had some compile difficulty until I added `-march=native`.  However, it's creating a vpcmpgtq instruction instead of pcmpgtq (no v), which is what I need for my test of valgrind.  Is there a way to use intrinsics and also force SSE?

Comment: Yes, use `-march=nehalem` or `-march=native -mno-avx`.  If AVX is available, compilers always use the VEX encoding when auto-vectorizing or for intrinsics.  (Nehalem is the last Intel uarch before AVX, so it's a good short-hand for SSE4.2 + popcnt etc, with tuning options more recent than generic baseline.  Or just `-msse4.1` of course to enable the ISA extensions you're trying to use extensions for, if you insist on pextrb instead of pmovmskb.)

Answer (score 5):

**This is possible with some asm hackery, but normally you'd be better off using intrinsics, like this**:
https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm

```
#include <immintrin.h>

template<int size, int element>
int foo(__m128i x, __m128i y) {
    if (size==32)                   // if constexpr if you want to be C++17 fancy
        x = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(x, y);
    else
        x = _mm_cmpgt_epi64(x, y);  // needs -msse4.2 or -march=native or whatever

    return x[element];  // GNU C extension to index vectors with [].
                        //  GCC defines __m128i as a vector of two long long
                        // cast to typedef int v4si __attribute__((vector_size(16)))
                        //  or use _mm_extract_epi8 or whatever with element*size/8
                        //  if you want to access one of 4 dword elements.
}

int test(__m128i x, __m128i y) {
    return foo<32, 0>(x, y);
}
// compiles to   pcmpgtd %xmm1, %xmm0   ;  movq    %xmm0, %rax    ; ret
```

You can even go full-on [GNU C native vector](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html#Vector-Extensions) style and do `x = x>y` after casting them to `v4si` or not, depending on whether you want 32 or 64-bit element compares.  GCC will implement the operator > however it can, with a multi-instruction emulation if SSE4.2 isn't available for pcmpgtq.  There's no other fundamental difference between that and intrinsics though; the compiler isn't required to emit `pcmpgtq` just because the source contained `_mm_cmpgt_epi64`, e.g. it can do constant-propagation through it if x and y are both compile-time constants, or if y is known to be LONG_MAX so nothing can be greater than it.

---

### Using inline asm

Only the C preprocessor could work the way you're hoping; the asm template has to be a string literal at compile time, and AFAIK C++ template constexpr stuff can't stringify and past a variable's value into an actual string literal.  Template evaluation happens after parsing.

**I came up with an amusing hack that gets GCC to print `d` or `q` as the asm symbol name of a global (or static) variable, using `%p4`** (See [operand modifiers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86Operandmodifiers) in the GCC manual.)  An empty array like `constexpr char d[] = {};` is probably a good choice here.  You can't pass string literals to template parameters anyway.

(I also fixed the inefficiencies and bugs in your inline asm statement: e.g. let the compiler pick registers, and ask for the inputs in XMM regs, not memory.  You were missing an "xmm7" clobber, but this version doesn't need any clobbers.  This is still worse than intrinsics for cases where the inputs might be compile-time constants, or where one was in aligned memory so could use a memory operand, or various other possible optimizations.  I could have used `"xm"` as a source but clang would always pick "m".  **https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm**.)

If you need it to not be optimized away for valgrind testing, maybe make it `asm volatile` to force it to run even if the output isn't needed.  That's about the only reason you'd want to use inline asm instead of intrinsics or GNU C native vector syntax (`x > y`)

```
typedef long long V64x2 __attribute__((vector_size(16), may_alias));
// or #include <immintrin.h> and use __m128i which is defined the same way


static constexpr char q[0] asm("q") = {}; // override asm symbol name which gets mangled for const or constexpr
static constexpr char d[0] asm("d") = {};

template <const char *op, int element_select>
static int cmpGT64Sx2(V64x2 x, V64x2 y)
{
   int result;
   __asm__(
           // AT&T style has destination second.
           "pcmpgt%p[op] %[src],%[dst]\n\t"   // %p4 - print the bare name, not $d or $q
           "pextrb %3, %[dst], %0"
           : "=r" (result), [dst]"+x"(x)
           : [src]"x"(y), "i" (element_select*8),
             [op]"i"(op)  // address as an immediate = symbol name
           : /* no clobbers */);
   return result;
}
int gt64(V64x2 x, V64x2 y) {
    return cmpGT64Sx2<q, 1>(x,y);
}

int gt32(V64x2 x, V64x2 y) {
    return cmpGT64Sx2<d, 1>(x,y);
}
```

So at the cost of having `d` and `q` as global-scope names in this file(!??), we can use `<d, 2>` or `<q, 0>` template params that look like the instruction we want.

Note that in x86 SIMD terminology, a "lane" is a 128-bit chunk of an AVX or AVX-512 vector.  As in [vpermilps](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermilps) (In-Lane Permute of 32-bit float elements).

This compiles to the following asm with GCC10 -O3 (https://godbolt.org/z/ovxWd8)

```
gt64(long long __vector(2), long long __vector(2)):
        pcmpgtq %xmm1,%xmm0
        pextrb $8, %xmm0, %eax
        ret
gt32(long long __vector(2), long long __vector(2)):
        pcmpgtd %xmm1,%xmm0
        pextrb $8, %xmm0, %eax    // This is actually element 2 of 4, not 1, because your scale doesn't account for the size.
        ret
```

---

**You can hide the global-scope vars from the template users and have them pass an integer size**.  I also fixed the element indexing to account for the variable element size.

```
static constexpr char q[0] asm("q") = {}; // override asm symbol name which gets mangled for const or constexpr
static constexpr char d[0] asm("d") = {};

template <int size, int element_select>
static int cmpGT64Sx2_new(V64x2 x, V64x2 y)
{
  //static constexpr char dd[0] asm("d") = {};  // nope, asm symbol name overrides don't work on local-scope static vars

   constexpr int bytepos = size/8 * element_select;
   constexpr const char *op = (size==32) ? d : q;
   // maybe static_assert( size == 32 || size == 64 )
   int result;
   __asm__(
         // AT&T style has destination second.
         "pcmpgt%p[op]   %[src],%[dst]\n\t"  // SSE2 or SSE4.2
         "pextrb         %[byte], %[dst], %0"     // SSE4.1
       : "=r" (result), [dst]"+x"(x)
       : [src]"x"(y), [byte]"i" (bytepos),
         [op]"i"(op)  // address as an immediate = symbol name
       : /* no clobbers */);
   return result;
}


// Note *not* referencing  d or q  static vars, but the template is
int gt64_new(V64x2 x, V64x2 y) {
    return cmpGT64Sx2_new<64, 1>(x,y);
}

int gt32_new(V64x2 x, V64x2 y) {
    return cmpGT64Sx2_new<32, 1>(x,y);
}
```

This also compiles like we want, e.g.

```
gt32_new(long long __vector(2), long long __vector(2)):
        pcmpgtd   %xmm1,%xmm0
        pextrb         $4, %xmm0, %eax       # note the correct element 1 position
        ret
```

BTW, you could use `typedef int v4si __attribute__((vector_size(16)))` and then `v[element]` to let GCC do it for you, if your asm statement just produces an `"=x"` output of that type in the same register as a `"0"(x)` input for example.

---

### Without global-scope var names, using GAS `.if` / `.else`

We can easily get GCC to print a bare number into the asm template, e.g. for use as an operand to [a `.if  %[size] == 32` directive](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/If.html#If).  The GNU assembler has some conditional-assembly features, so we just get GCC to feed it the right text input to use that.  Much less of a hack on the C++ side, but less compact source.  Your template param could be a `'d'` or `'q'` size-code character if you wanted to compare on that instead of a size number.

```
template <int size, int element_select>
static int cmpGT64Sx2_mask(V64x2 x, V64x2 y)
{
   constexpr int bytepos = size/8 * element_select;
   unsigned int result;
   __asm__(
         // AT&T style has destination second.
         ".if %c[opsize] == 32\n\t"         // note Godbolt hides directives; use binary mode to verify the assemble-time condition worked
         "pcmpgtd   %[src],%[dst]\n\t"  // SSE2
         ".else \n\t"
         "pcmpgtq   %[src],%[dst]\n\t"  // SSE4.2
         ".endif \n\t"
         "pmovmskb       %[dst], %0"
       : "=r" (result), [dst]"+x"(x)
       : [src]"x"(y),   [opsize]"i"(size)  // address as an immediate = symbol name
       : /* no clobbers */);
   return (result >> bytepos) & 1;   // can just be TEST when branching on it
}
```

I also changed to using SSE2 `pmovmskb` to extract both / all element compare results, and using scalar stuff to select which bit to look at.  This is orthogonal and can be used with any others.  After inlining, it's generally going to be more efficient, allowing `test $imm32, %eax`.  (pmovmskb is cheaper than pextrb, and it lets the whole thing require only SSE2 for the pcmpgtd version).

The *asm* output from the compiler looks like

```
        .if 64 == 32
        pcmpgtd   %xmm1,%xmm0
        .else 
        pcmpgtq   %xmm1,%xmm0
        .endif 
        pmovmskb       %xmm0, %eax
```

To make sure that did what we want, we can assemble to *binary* and look at disassembly (https://godbolt.org/z/5zGdfv):

```
gt32_mask(long long __vector(2), long long __vector(2)):
 pcmpgtd %xmm1,%xmm0
 pmovmskb %xmm0,%eax
 shr    $0x4,%eax
 and    $0x1,%eax
```

(and gt64_mask uses `pcmpgtq` and `shr` by 8.)

Comment: Thanks! For this usage of Valgrind, it's crucial that the instruction is precisely pcmpgt*. I can't guarantee that other instructions like vpcmpgt* have been instrumented. In my testing, I saw that the compiler might generate different opcodes.

Comment: @Eyal: If you use `-mno-avx`, GCC and clang will definitely not emit `vpcmpgt*` from intrinsics.  But like I said, they can in theory optimize away intrinsics, e.g. if `y` is known to be `_mm_set1_epi32(INT_MAX)` or `_mm_set1_epi64x(LLONG_MAX)` so nothing can be greater.

Comment: @Eyal: if this is just for testing something about valgrind, sure inline asm makes sense.  If this is part of a real program that you're manually vectorizing for performance, use intrinsics.  (And compile it with `-O3 -march=native -mno-avx` when you want to use valgrind on it.  Or maybe just `-march=nehalem -mtune=native` if valgrind doesn't know about other new instructions like BMI2 `shlx`)